# Simplify a matrix expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing an exercise but I am not quite sure which answer is the right one. Can I have your advice on it, please?

Exercise: Let A be a symmetrical matrix of order n which admits an inverse matrix. Let B be an antisymmetric matrix of order n. Let C be an order matrix n. Which expression is equivalent to:[image] 
(G means "None of these answers")

**I try to simplify the expression to see which one matched the answers listed, but I a stuck.**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is symmetric, thus, $A^T=A$; B is antisymmetric, thus, $B^T=-B$. This implies that
$$
A^TC^TB^T+A^T+B^T-A-B= AC^T(-B)+(A^T-A)+-B-B=-AC^TB-2B.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help @AVK!